# Hardware or kernel issue?

Tags: kernel

I have these errors in debian buster with kernel 4.14.13 with intel z370 chipset:

```
ACPI Error: [_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PXSX] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170728/dswload2-191)
ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20170728/psobject-252)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.RP04.PXSX, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170728/psparse-550)
ACPI Error: [_SB_.PCI0.RP09.PXSX] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170728/dswload2-191)
ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20170728/psobject-252)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.RP08.PXSX, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170728/psparse-550)
pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e4(Receiver ID)
pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:   device [8086:a294] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
```

Found out that pcieport are related do asmedia usb 3.1 controler. I am wondering if these errors are hardware or software issue ?

Comment: Upgrade your BIOS, for some people it helped.

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson Unfortunately I have latest